# Is it possible to paste in edit mode?

Tags: workflow, shortcut

Is there any way to use paste in edit mode, because in edit mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> is replaced by the vertices menu.

I can copy things fine but it is impossible to paste. Of course I could use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate but is there a way to copy?

Comment: You can use ctrl-c ctrl-v in object mode...

Comment: @GiantCowFilms when you use ctrl+v in edit mode you get the vertices menu, you can't paste.

Comment: When in Edit mode, all that you are operating will be nothing but elemtents, so why not just using **Shift D** instead of Ctrl C and Ctrl V?

Comment: What are you expecting this to do? Are you trying to paste geometry from another file? You could paste in object mode and then join the objects..

Comment: @gandalf3 If I have a bunch of vertices selected and I copy them is there any way to paste them without using duplicate?

Comment: @Qwertieϟ Why would you want to? Copy paste is two steps, shift+D is one..

Comment: @gandalf3 I was just wondering if it was possible to use paste. duplicate is quicker but it seems odd that there would be a shortcut over paste.

Comment: When copying vertices from one object and pasting them in another, duplicate obviously won't work. What about that use case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can invoke copy and paste using the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> menu (it shows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> as shortcut for paste, but as you said that doesn't work). Simply press <kbd>Space</kbd> and search for `copy` and `paste` and use the appropriate entries from the list.

> As pointed out by GiantCowFilms, the copy / paste functions work at object level. So even if you use them in edit mode, the whole object gets duplicated and not your selection!

Because you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate, there seems to be no need for copy and paste.

Comment: No, its not a bug. the copy and paste options work on the object level.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms thanks, I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> When copying vertices from one object and pasting them in another, duplicate obviously won't work. What about that use case?

You could duplicate, then "p" separate, which would create a new copied object of your duplication. You could then join that to any other object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with this add-on: 
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/CutCopyPaste3D

With CTRL-insert you copy mesh data in edit mode, switch to another object and enter edit mode, and using SHIFT-insert pastes the mesh data.